# How do I display registration errors in Rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I have a simple Rack app, here is the sign up part :

```
class SignUp
  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)

    if req.post?
      User.register(req.params)
      [ 301, { 'Location' => '/login' }, [] ]
    else
      [ 200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, [File.read('signup.html')]]
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to do is display an error if the password is too short, how do I do that? I have a signup.html page and that's where I want to display the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to use rack for that?

Rack is too low-level instrument.

But anyway, you can return errors hash from `User.register(req.params)` method

Then you can use ERB for template preparation, and pass this hash with template to ERB, that will render form with errors.

Check out http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

Comment: I was lead to believe that understanding Rack is the key to understand Rails.

Comment: Probably, but rack is more suitable for micro-tasks, like filtering, or something else.
Everything that can be done before rails processing.